# upload file with ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

I allow users to either post a comment on an article but i would also like to add the ability for users to `upload photos` via `ajax` so no `refresh` takes place...

i have `searched` `many` `plugins` but most of them are too overwhelmed for what i am trying to achieve...

I have the UI and the `backend`...i just want to know how to make the file `pass from the client to the server` i can check/store it etc...

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/ - I have used it with CodeIgniter in the past. The only gotcha (see http://codeigniter.com/wiki/SWFUpload for a little more information) is the Mime type. I have been able to get around this by inspecting the $_FILES and getting the correct mime type this way.

Comment: @Gavin thanks for the suggestion but currently im not looking into flash.

Comment: The only other solutions are IFrames (http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/) or HTML5 (http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/07/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload the problem is solved.

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept this answer if it answers your question.